# Is there a way to draw a filled area with Canvas without using Path?

Tags: android, android-canvas, custom-draw

I am wondering if there is **a way to draw filled areas (like a filled polygon) with the Android Canvas without using** the `Path` class and call `canvas.drawPath(...)`.

The reason I want to do this without `Path` is because I have to draw very large datasets and `canvas.drawPath(...)` is not hardware accelerated and therefore slow.

The performance when using `canvas.drawLines(...)` is much better because of hardware acceleration, however I have not found a way to draw the polygon filled using this approach (even when the lines are all connected).

Even calling `paint.setStyle(Style.FILL)` did not fill the polygon when using `drawLines(...)`.

Is there a way to draw a filled-polygon without using the `Path` approach?

Or **is there any other way** to improve performance using the `Canvas`?

Comment: Is your `view` interactive (do you have changes to your dataset on the fly that need to be rendered)? Simply drawing your dataset to the `canvas` once is slow?

Comment: My View is interactive and therefore constantly refreshed, I am already using a buffering mechanism, which greatly improved performance. However, I am not satisfied yet.

Comment: My last question to elaborate an answer. When a change occurs to your dataset are you drawing the whole dataset again or just the ones affected in the area of change? I mean, are you already using the `view.invalidate(Rect dirty)`? This is just a tip to improve the performance.

Comment: That's actually a very good idea. But I think it cannot be used in my case since I'm drawing a chart and when it is e.g. zoomed in and scrolled, the whole view needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Do you want to start a conversation? I worked on android drawing app and had some issues like this. I can share some of my "know-how" if you want.

Comment: Sure, would be great :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73157/discussion-between-tato-rodrigo-and-philipp-jahoda).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at opengl view and use it for all the drawings you need. Definitely will be damn fast. Still, all your drawing code needs to be re-written.

Comment: Not really answering the question, which is asking specifically for a solution using the `Canvas`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that OpenGL ES is faster. However, it is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something like :

```
Paint red = new Paint();

red.setColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

And use this color for your path, instead of your ARGB. Make sure the last point of your path ends on the first one, it makes sense also.